# If every cell in a creature's body were replaced by a functionally identical nanobot, would the creature retain its consciousness?

Tags: internal-consistency, xenobiology, robots

If every cell in a creature's body were replaced (as in Theseus's Ship), would the creature still have its consciousness?  E.g. a white blood cell would be destroyed and replaced by a nanobot that flows around the bloodstream, killing foreign substances; an interneuron would be replaced by a nanobot that sends an electrical impulse when it detects acetylcholine, etc.

Reality-checking [Phyresis](http://mtgsalvation.gamepedia.com/Compleation) from *Magic the Gathering* here.

Comment: This question may be more appropriate on [philosophy.se] - I think it's far too speculative even for this site.

Comment: No, such a creature would *not* be conscious; however, it would *believe* that it was. - Unless, of course, it was programmed not to.

Comment: @A.I.Breveleri so do you believe *you* are concious?

Comment: It probably will, but it will be other ship, and we can say that definitely on each step of replacement, on each intermediate phase, not only about end result. There is fundamental difference. Not sure if it possible to feel and look as original, but even if, it will be a different thing. Connected to previous, just like drawing is connected to result. It is not like Theseus's Ship.

Comment: Far beyond our current understanding of consciousness. The only real answer we have today is "Don't know."

Comment: The real question is, why do you have to replace my cells to make a copy of me?  Since that's all this is.

Comment: @JDługosz: It depends on whether I consider my belief subjectively or objectively. Subjectively, of course, I *feel* intuitively that I must be conscious, because I think. Objectively, however, since I am actually a highly complex artificial intelligence created by superprogrammer Donald MacIntyre to prowl the web and consistently pass the Turing test, I *know* that I am not.

Comment: You might try weighing in on [thus question](http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/40663/how-can-you-have-dualism-in-hard-sf) if you think there is a fundamental difference.

Comment: @A.I.Breveleri You're not alone. And who said that you weren't conscious? Whatever happened to "I think, therefore I am"?

Comment: It might have 'a' consciousness, would would it be the same consciousness?  Triggers Broom springs to mind. (Ship of Theseus paradox for those uneducated in British sitcoms).

Comment: If your nanobots act in an identical manner then by definition it would act in the same way as the person. You can't know if any person is having a conscious experience and the same applies here.

Comment: "Cogito Ergo Sum." It is impossible to prove that anyone but oneself is conscious. Since it is impossible to prove consciousness exists to begin with, it is impossible to determine if it may be transferred.

Comment: @A.I.Breveleri [Welcome to the club.](http://i.imgur.com/gUnJVZ4.jpg)

Comment: @Tomáš Zato: *Worldbuilding SE* comment threads often become brainstorm sessions for brain droppings that might form the seed of a story idea. - For example: I thought up this comment while I *believed* I was shitting, but my simulation engine was only simulating the activity. So, what happened to the virtual turd after I pushed the virtual flush handle? Obviously the *garbage collector* took care of it. Story idea: *What happens to the garbage objects after collection but before the storage is re-used?* Can they interact at all? Do they have their own stories?

Comment: You may find [John Searle's "Chinese room" thought experiment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_room) relevant.

Comment: If every nanobot was functionally equivalent to the cell it replaced, I do not see why not. IMO it would be conscious, but unless it can store the information acquired over the lifetime of that creature (memories) it will essentially be a different individual than the original.

Answer (score 30):

Truth is - No one knows.

We are so far from perfectly replicating single neuron, and so far from understanding what consciousness is, that no one can tell.

Good thing is - both "yes" and "no" are believable answers in the (lack of) light of current science, so use whichever you need.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44320/discussion-on-answer-by-molot-if-every-cell-in-a-creatures-body-were-replaced-b).

Answer (score 27):

**Yes, by definition**

If you're replace something with something that is functionally identical then *by definition* it must be functionally indistinguishable from the thing it replaces. If replacing the cells with nanobots doesn't reproduce consciousness then they're *not functionally identical*.

The more interesting question is whether it is possible to replace the cells with nanobots and preserve function.

Comment: This is the only really correct answer here. The OP has defined the answer in the question itself via their wording.

Comment: You would have to be very knowledgeable to understand all that "functionally identical" entails of course. I'm not a doctor, but I believe that an interruption of the electrical patterns in the brain would be comparable to a seizure. So the replacement must not only reproduce function, but also immediate state. There are very short lived aspects of the cell's state that have to be maintained to avoid a temporary interruption of consciousness. If replacement occurred one cell at a time over a long enough period of time I assume this wouldn't be an issue.

Comment: But it would be a different individual UNLESS it could also copy the stored information (eg memories) from the original cell.

Comment: @DJMethaneMan  Oh right. A memory cannot be stored in an individual cell but the networks of synaptic connections between neurons collectively hold memories. So the difference between functionally identical to a brain cell and this exact brain cell, is the difference between retaining all memories and probably ending up dead from the medulla "forgetting" how to keep your heart pumping and lungs breathing.

Comment: You should preface your answer with, "From a purely materialistic viewpoint", While this is the viewpoint I agree with, I can see no way to establish it as a certainty,

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast: I'm not going to engage in a discussion about whether it's necessary to hat-tip woo-woo in every answer but in this case it makes no difference: if changing the cells with nanobots removes conciousness then they are _not_ functionally identical. What provides consciousness is irrelevant.

Answer (score 17):

That depends. Do you believe that consciousness is a consequence of having a soul? If not, then if the nanobots faithfully simulate all cell activity, there is every reason to believe that consciousness would be preserved. In this view, consciousness is an emergent property of neural function given the organizational constraints which derive from our brain structure.

If you want something more mystical and less prosaic, then the existence of a soul would presumably not be supported by mere machinery. As to the point of replacement/failure of consciousness, that is not answerable until someone can quantify/qualify consciousness. And that does not seem to be likely any time soon.

Comment: We need to quantify/define consciousness to answer this question, I agree. A "good" definition would then automatically answer the question.

Answer (score 13):

Most of the body would not matter one bit. Is a man with a wodden leg still concious? You could change the limbs, bone, blood, intestines, etc. without having any effect on his mind.

As for the **brain**, replacing a brain cell with a nanomachine that works in exactly the same way would do the trick. It would have to connect to other cells in the same way and have the same behavior. A living cell *is* a complex nanomachine. So consider replacing the cell with another exactly like it.

[Everything we know informs us](http://www.preposterousuniverse.com/blog/2011/05/23/physics-and-the-immortality-of-the-soul/) that consciousness arises from the physics of the atoms making up the brain. (See [this question](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/40663/how-can-you-have-dualism-in-hard-sf) to explore otherwise; and comments and references concerning this fact.)  So if a brain cell were replaced with a *different* nanomachine that was in fact behaviorally identical, it would make to difference.

Answer (score 6):

You are talking about replacing every single cell in a body, which means nothing original would be left. In that case, how is it different from creating a new clone?

If you create a new clone, you would probably have a new human there. The new human would probably be considered conscious, because it moves, but the old human doesn't get unconscious either, if it is a good clone that doesn't affect the original body. So the problem is, is it just the same consciousness, or a new one?

Meanwhile, you can't say that the person becomes unconscious. Consider a person whose neurones are all replaced except the last one. Each other cell is perfectly cloned. As a cell unit, the last cell is still conscious.

If the person is perfectly cloned, to other people it seems that he is still conscious, because he will act like what he was before. But what about the original consciousness? Well, that's the same question as what happens after a person dies ‐ nobody knows.

If you believe in souls, you can mention that neurones are just a physical carrier of a soul, and that nanobots can or cannot carry a soul, depending on your requirements. Does the soul get surgically removed when the brain cells are surgically removed? This is up to you as well. It might even get torn apart by the surgery.
Someone has once hypothesized that a cloned human would have the physiological capabilities like an animal, but not the wisdom of a human. Nevertheless, considering the hypothesis that intelligence memory is probably stored in the brain, this might not be true as well.

Comment: If you suppose there is something beyond the physical functioning of the components, try addressing it as an answer to [this question](http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/40663/how-can-you-have-dualism-in-hard-sf).

Answer (score 5):

Consciousness is the result of the brain, a mixture of senses,memories and a complex communication between the neurons.

To make an example see neurons as people, having 10 people there doesn't do anything.

But if you give those 10 people something to talk about they will create a conversation, this conversation is the consciousness of the group.

If one of the ten people dies and gets replaced the conversation and so the consciousness will change and lose or gain new qualities.

Over time these 10 people will die and be replaced  causing the conversation to deviate completely from the original group.

In short, we all die slowly over time until there's nothing left of what we used to be.

Replacing the neurons of a person with nanobots would be exactly like killing that person and having someone replace them that thinks to be them.

another Example:

1-Jimmy is alive and knows it.

2-Every single cell in jimmy's body  gets replaced by nanobots.

3-Jimmy is killed by the nanobots.

4-The nanobots give life to Jimmy-bot.

5-Jimmy-bot is alive and knows it.

6-Jimmy-bot doesn't remember about the existence of the original Jimmy therefore now Jimmy-bot became the true original Jimmy leaving the old one in the oblivion.

Comment: Even after you reach adulthood, your cells are being routinely replaced all the time. This is true, to a lesser extant, even in the brain. [Adult Neruogenesis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adult_neurogenesis)

Answer (score 4):

This is essentially a new take on an ancient (and I do mean  ancient) thought experiment.

The Ship of Theseus. Discussed by Plato and other ancient philosophers.

If you have a ship/boat, and every single component is replaced with an identical replacement (no upgrades). Is it still the same boat?

There are other variations, such as the grandfather axe, where both the axe handle and axe head are replaced.

Your question asks about whether the nanobot body would still be conscious. I think another very important thing to take into account is, is it even the same consciousness?!

Comment: When I first read your question. I didn't see you had Theseus ship in brackets. Did you edit the question?! I think I need to go back to bed...

Comment: It is not like Theseus ship, quantum mechanically

Comment: @MolbOrg, "if every cell is replaced"!!! How is that not Theseus ship. If every cell is replaced the quantum mechanics would be acting on different cells...the actions of the quantum mechanics might be the same regardless, and it could be different...but isn't that the entire point of the thought experiment? Is it the same, or is it different?

Comment: long story, definitively not for the comments, and probably mater of perception, but if about ship example - if u replace parts not with the wood parts, but steel - I would say at the end it will be different ship, then at the begin. Active parts of cells, everything that makes them work - are not macro objects but numerous molecules. This molecules interaction mesh is that what makes us happening. Even(highly doubt in that) it is possible to find same solution for that system in other therms(other molecules), the whole reason for such replacement is just incompatible with such solutions.

Answer (score 4):

Technically, your body does this every ~1 year. And do you lose consciousness every year?

Comment: +1, but it’s worth noting that some cells in the body aren’t replaced. Their *constituents* are, but continuously, not abruptly. And, as Mołot commented elsewhere, this is a potentially important caveat.

Comment: Could you expand a bit on it? Here on Worldbuilding, we usually like more consistent answers. And without it, yours looks more like a comment than an actual answer.

Comment: Yes neurons being replaced are the very first reason for why many memories don't simply get lost but are completely erased.

Comment: Brain cells do not regenerate, when they die, they are gone.

Comment: Someone argues that cells are not that important, only connections are, and brain connections continue to grow during whole life. (just hypotesis, one of the most active research area)

Comment: @CemKalyoncu on the back of a person's head there's enough stem cells to grow the brain by 8%-12%, these stem cells can also be used to replace dead neurons. And white matter always increases.

Comment: But they don't work that way as of now, you cannot use that to back every cell in your body change every year. Also, I forgot to tell before, most of your heart muscles do not get replaced (they don't die easily).

Answer (score 3):

Depends on your definition of consciousness.

If you define consciousness as a state of matter (materialist way), then yes. However from that point of view, consciousness itself is meaningless word and everything can be said to have it, even rocks.

However if you believe there is some unique spiritual value bound to consciousness (eg. soul) then no, because method you propose allows (or would allow) for duplication of this entity and we said it's unique.

Comment: no one prevent a spirit from being bound to a particular state of matter, so we can have both spirit and consciousness in a body replaced by nanobots

Comment: The problem is that if you can replace body with nanobots, you can probably also create a copy of it. That's where the problem is, if there are two copies, which one is the original?

Comment: exactly, who will be the spirit in the body? the nanobot spirit or the flesh one?

Comment: If you think the second paragraph might be the case, please weigh in on [this question](http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/40663/how-can-you-have-dualism-in-hard-sf).

Answer (score 1):

Assume you retain no consciousness after the process, since you interact with the world using your human interface (you know hands, feet, eyes etc.) and you already stated that cells keeps their functionality, then replacing each cell by keeping the same functionality keeps the interface functioning with the rest of the world, then you appear to be conscious even if you are not.

So I could ask about your conciousness and you would still answer like if you were conscious making that not distinguishable.

**Conclusion:**
Either you are not conscious already or you will remain conscious after the replacement.

Answer (score -1):

I think there is a fundamental flaw in your question, and that is that each cell is replaced by *one nanobot*. While that might (*might*) work for a red blood cell, or a WBC, or a muscle cell, there are no cells in the body with as many interconnections as neurons.

Each neuron may be connected to up to 10,000 other neurons. One nanobot cannot possibly perform the same as a biological neuron.

So no, there would be no mind or consciousness above the level of primitive organisms.

Comment: why can't some fictional nano bot have 10,000 connections?  It seems like a large jump

Comment: "up to 10,000 other neurons. One nanobot cannot possibly perform" - yes, it can  - the OP said so. This is part of the givens of this question. A cell *is* a nanobot.

Comment: a nanobot is nothing more than a cell made of different materials.....

Comment: Is the objection just that a nanobot the size of a neuron arguably is a "microbot", not a "nanobot"? If so then I think we have to surrender to the imprecise use the prefix "nano" to mean "so small as to be futuristic" ;-)

Comment: @SteveJessop Thanks, I was/am unaware of the terminology. I will do more searching before answering in the future. :)

Comment: @sdrawkcabdear -Because it wouldn't be micro then? Sorry, not a huge scifi reader.

Comment: actually electronic processors are as small as 10 nanometers   while a neuron is 100 micrometers ... So yeah nanobots are smaller than cells. It would be possible  to make a more complex cell out of hundred of nanobots that would be a hundred of times more efficient than a neuron.

Comment: Actually, depending on your definition of nanobots, if it really doesn't work electronically, simply reproduce the structure of a neurone. I don't know why the OP wants to replace the cells with nanobots, but if they are really functionally identical, I don't think it is wrong if you make nanobots with proteins instead. Many modern edge-cutting appliances use biological principles as well.

Comment: Even if it is really not big enough, considering that the skin is made up of nanobots as well, that the brain size of a person varies over time already, and that some other cells (such as bone cells) can be smaller in size (because they are bots), I don't think it is a big deal that a human-like structure (it is controversial to call it a human after all) with a swelling brain can survive.

Comment: @渡し守シャロン - I'm sorry to disagree, but as a doctor and former molecular biologist,  your claim that you can make something with hundreds of nanobots that would be more efficient than a cell (never mind a neuron) only shows that you don't understand the magnitude of complexity of a cell. An actual nanobot right now is pretty simple.

Comment: it doesn't mean humanity can't create something more complex than what nature did....